# Stopping a server I never started?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, lighttpd

I've recently installed lighttpd but I can't run it because there's a daemon that starts an Apache2 server. I removed Apache 2 from the system but there's still a server running. How do I stop this so I can start lighttpd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/init.d/apache2 stop` will work in most cases on linux operating systems.

also using `ps aux` , finding the process ID and using `kill -9 id` (not 100% of what signal to send for a graceful termination)

Comment: On a Debian system, which Ubuntu is, the prescribed way to do it is `invoke-rc.d apache2 stop`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `/etc/init.d/httpd stop` if the above comment didn't work. It depends on the distro of course.

Also to stop apache starting again after a reboot you will want to run:

`update-rc.d -f apache2 remove`